# How can I delete multiple comment lines?

Tags: c#, regex, multiline

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
static string StripComments(string code)
{
    var re = @"(@(?:""[^""]*"")+|""(?:[^""\n\\]+|\\.)*""|'(?:[^'\n\\]+|\\.)*')|//.*|/\*(?s:.*?)\*/";
    return Regex.Replace(code, re, "$1");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a read of the description of the tag `regexp-replace` | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp-replace | `Function in Oracle, Mysql, Hive, Teradata, DB2, Snowflake, Trino, Vertica, PostgreSQL, Redshift and other databases...`

Comment: why not just `\/\*.+\*\/` with `RegexOptions.SingleLine`? | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aaowMN/1

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach the problem from a different angle:

1. Replace the name
2. Replace the web address
3. Replace the email

Comment: I would doubt that the information would be the same, because if that is the case I would question than not simply search and replace on all files? Why do I need code to remove 3 fixed values, is search/replace for 3 values to much work?

Answer (score 0):

**Look into this :**
This code removes the /* */ comments only .

Link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/PlR7L4

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;           
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string subjectString = @"Hello1

Hello2

/*Hello3

Hello4*/

Hello5

/*/if (!IsPostBack)
            //{
            //*/    //binddummyDT();
               
            //};
            ";
        Regex comments2 = new Regex(@"/\*(.|\n)*?\*/");
        string afterRemoval = comments2.Replace(subjectString, "");
        Console.WriteLine(afterRemoval);

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: FYI - `(.|\n)` thats what the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` is for | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions | `Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n). For more information, see the "Single-line Mode" section in the Regular Expression Options article.`